# Update object value in array with values in other array using hashtables or hashmap

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I have two arrays `Array1` and `Array2`, i am updating rate of object in `Array1` with rate of same object (With same ID) in Array 2. I have a functions that loops through both arrays to get desired result. After going through some of the answers on Stack overflow I feel Hash table is best suited to reduce the complexity. I was just curious to understand how same can be implemented using the has maps.

```js
let Array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "IceCream",
    details: [{
        id: "12",
        name: "milk",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "100"
      },
      {
        id: "13",
        name: "cream",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "300"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Coffee",
    details: [{
        id: "14",
        name: "Coffee bean",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "200"
      },
      {
        id: "15",
        name: "water",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "300"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tea",
    details: [{
      id: "16",
      name: "Tea leaf",
      quantity: "50",
      rate: "700"
    }]
  }
]
let Array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "IceCream",
    details: [{
        id: "12",
        name: "milk",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "500"
      },
      {
        id: "13",
        name: "cream",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "700"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Coffee",
    details: [{
        id: "14",
        name: "Coffee bean",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "800"
      },
      {
        id: "15",
        name: "water",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "8000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
Array1 = Array1.map(item => {
  let element = Array2.find(e => e.id == item.id);
  if (element) {
    item.details = item.details.map(e => {
      let detail = element.details.find(d => d.id == e.id);
      if (detail)
        e.rate = detail.rate;
      return e;
    });
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(Array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a map of `Array2`'s items (by id) and each of `Array2`'s details (by id), and then you can iterate over `Array1` and mutate its properties with low complexity:

```
const items2ById = {};
for (const item of Array2) {
  items2ById[item.id] = item;
}
const items2DetailsById = {};
for (const detail of Array2.flatMap(({ details }) => details)) {
  items2DetailsById[detail.id] = detail;
}
for (const item of Array1) {
  if (!items2ById[item.id]) continue;
  for (const detail of item.details) {
    if (items2DetailsById[detail.id]) {
      detail.rate = items2DetailsById[detail.id].rate;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that since you're mutating the existing objects, `.map` isn't really appropriate, since you don't really care to create a new array - instead, just iterate over the array and mutate it as needed.

```js
let Array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "IceCream",
    details: [{
        id: "12",
        name: "milk",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "100"
      },
      {
        id: "13",
        name: "cream",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "300"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Coffee",
    details: [{
        id: "14",
        name: "Coffee bean",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "200"
      },
      {
        id: "15",
        name: "water",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "300"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tea",
    details: [{
      id: "16",
      name: "Tea leaf",
      quantity: "50",
      rate: "700"
    }]
  }
]
let Array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "IceCream",
    details: [{
        id: "12",
        name: "milk",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "500"
      },
      {
        id: "13",
        name: "cream",
        quantity: "50",
        rate: "700"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Coffee",
    details: [{
        id: "14",
        name: "Coffee bean",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "800"
      },
      {
        id: "15",
        name: "water",
        quantity: "60",
        rate: "8000"
      }
    ]
  }
];
const items2ById = {};
for (const item of Array2) {
  items2ById[item.id] = item;
}
const items2DetailsById = {};
for (const detail of Array2.flatMap(({ details }) => details)) {
  items2DetailsById[detail.id] = detail;
}
for (const item of Array1) {
  if (!items2ById[item.id]) continue;
  for (const detail of item.details) {
    if (items2DetailsById[detail.id]) {
      detail.rate = items2DetailsById[detail.id].rate;
    }
  }
}
console.log(Array1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works like magic..I am trying to get my head around maps can you refer good resource..Thanks again!!

Comment: A "Map" in JS generally refers to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map, a data structure which I'm not using here. The `items2ById` and `items2DetailsById` are just plain objects, which connect a property name to a value.